# PsExec and calling batch files

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I'm going to try and break this down as simple as I can.

There are three computers involved.  Local machine (LM), compute node (CN), and data node (DN) will be their names from here on out.

I have a psexec command which calls a batch file on the compute node.

```
psexec \\"compute node" -w WorkingDirectory BatchFileName
```

This BatchFileName sets some local variables then an executable which is located in the WorkingDirectory.  This executable loads, but it has a configuration file which points to a bunch of files located on the data node.  This is where my operation breaks down.  If I run the batch locally on the compute node everything works fine.  I'm merely trying to call it from a local machine using psexec instead.  The same account name and password are used for all computers in this case.

The error I get is that it can't open the file located on the data node.

Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set VALUATION_DATE=20090313
set LiTEShome=C:\LiTES
ServiceConsole.exe
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

ServiceConsole.exe.config contains:

```
<add key="SomeName" value="\\Data Node\\Directory\\FileName"/>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
psexec \"compute node" -w WorkingDirectory BatchFileName -u UserName -p Password
```

with an account that has permissions on both nodes.